# Nameconflict in c# Enum with property

Tags: c#

Unfortunately I have managed to name one of classes one particular property the same as an Enum. It is saved in the database and the Entity Framework so I am not sure I want to change it for the reason I am afraid that I will mess up my whole project.
My problem is, that when I want to acces both in the same method, the Enum is not available, my guess is because of the name conflict.
Is there any way I can fix this beside changes everything from the database up?
Thank for the advice.

Comment: Access the enum using its full name?

Comment: You can also introduce an alias through using `using EnumType = FullNameOfMyEnum;` if typing the full name repeatedly is necessary but burdensome (and you can of course in some sense "alias" the property through `private [type] alias => property`, though this introduces an actual new property that you may need to prevent from getting saved).

Comment: You can use the full namespace. Also ***don't*** be afraid to refactor your code, this is a common part of maintenance and architecture. Work in a different branch and test db to make sure it all works. Its better to spend time making a good readable maintainable design than keep hacking a bad one